# What is the best way to compare two text file by rows and column in java

Tags: java

*File comparison* : I've come across the requirement to compare two files by each row and column, I was just looking for an opinion on the best and tased approach. I could use comparator into an object of each row value and see what's the difference and consolidate at the end.
    I was looking for showing the exact position, line and value which is not matching.

```
Use Case : I have 2 text file having the below content, to compare the content

**FILE1.txt**                   
Name    Age     Address     postcode       
John    25      Amsterdam   1111fg          
Steve   40      Breda       4343 jv         

**FILE2.txt**
Name    Age     Address postcode  
Andrew  25      Harleem 2222 jb  
Steve   40      Breda   4343 jv  



So the expected response should be :

Address : File 1 = Hoofddorp, File 2 = Harleem
postcode : File 1 = 2132 Kv, File 2 = 2132 jb
```

Comment: You could give more details on the files, and provide some basic code to compare two multiline strings. Else your question is very broad, opinion based, and not well for for this site.

Comment: Are all lines present in both files or is it possible lines have been added or deleted?

Comment: We could have now line missing in first or second file

Comment: Please provide the expected result base on the example given.

Comment: So the expected response is :

Address in File 1 = Hoofddorp File 2 = Harleem
postcode File 1 = 2132 Kv File 2 = 2132 jb

Answer (score 1):

First test if files are different by comparing two files byte by byte
Example using guava:

```
Files.asByteSource(file1).contentEquals(Files.asByteSource(file2));
```

If files are different analyze further to display the exact column.

Comment: What do you recommend to analyse further as the fastest way?